# not able to assign value to list declare in model in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My Model **Question_Bank_Model**:

```
public List<string> Options { get; set; }
```

My Controller

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Question_IdLIst.Count; i++)
  {
     Question_Bank_Model Question = new Question_Bank_Model();
     Question.Question = QuestionBal.FetchQuestion_ByQuestionID(Question_IdLIst[i]);
   List<string> Options_Value = QuestionBal.FetchOption_ByQuestion(Question_IdLIst[i]);
             for (int j = 0; j < Options_Value.Count ; j++)
              {
                  Question.Options[j] = Options_Value.ElementAt(j);

              }
               q.Add(Question);
   }
```

i am getting value in **Options_Value** in this list but it is throwing error on

`Question.Options[j] = Options_Value.ElementAt(j);` line

Error:Object reference not set to instance of object.

can any one help me???

Comment: You forgot to initialize the `Options` list of `Question` object. Currently it is null

Comment: where i forgot to initialise ?

Comment: It is up to you where exactly you initialize it. It can be done in constructor of the class, in the property getter, or in the controller after you created a question instance.

Comment: can u please show me through the code.i am not geeting it.m badly struck on it.

Comment: After `new Question_Bank_Model()` line do something like `Question.Options = new List<string>();`. This should do it

Comment: in my controller naa?

Comment: Yes, in the controller. Just after the line `Question_Bank_Model Question = new Question_Bank_Model();`.And you might want to lookup some articles about reference types in .NET

Comment: @Andrei:thank u so much.ur solution works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
Question.Options = new List<string>(); 

for (int j = 0; j < Options_Value.Count ; j++)
{
    Question.Options.Add(Options_Value.ElementAt(j));
}
```

Thanks!